# Valarray in c++ don't want to return element

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, valarray

Need help with valarray.
Here is my code:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <complex>

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

//some code

CArray *abc = new CArray(10);
Complex mem = abc[5]; //Error here
```

It complaints that there are no suitable conversion from CArray to Complex. Why it tries to return something of CArray type?! Thanks in advance

P.S.

```
'std::valarray<Complex>::operator[]' non-standart syntax; use'&' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating your valarray? It is (almost|always) never a good thing to do.

Comment: I very much doubt that "non-standart syntax" is part of the actual error message. Please use copy & paste.

Comment: @SergeyA that helped. Actually i totally forgot about resize method